# Cross server webservice using ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, web-services

Hi stackoverflow users.

My server setup is the following:
A webserver with access on http/80 running www.domain.com
A app server with access to the internal network (db etc.) running a webservice

I have this simple little server setup problem.

Now I want to call my webservice from a ajax script from a website on my webserver. But since my application server does not have access to the internet this will (in my mind) not be possible since the javascript (running in the end-users browser) shoud have access to that webservice.

I came up with the solution by inventing a webservice on the webserver calling the webservice on my application server, but thats a odd solution, does any of you have a idea how to solve this?

Comment: Here is my setup http://billedeupload.dk/images/ZV1BW.png

Comment: Does the webserver running http/80 do anything?  Or does it just proxy the call?

Comment: it does run the webserver and has access to the internal network on one network card and the internet on another...

Comment: Using a proxy server is how I have dealt with similar problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this. You will have to provide some thing on WebServer using which end user can access your App Server.

You have multiple options for this

- PageMethods
- Web Services on WebServer which will relay ajax calls to the App Server

Hope this info helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are just just using a webservice as a proxy through some network firewalls.  There are tools that will do this for you, however, if you are running a simple service, then I don't see a problem with your setup.

One such tool for IIS is [Application Request Routing](http://www.iis.net/download/ApplicationRequestRouting)

Comment: Does you have any examples of using this with webservices. It seams that it is build for streaming media and caching data and not for rerouting webservices...

Comment: According to security issues I am going to stick with the solution with two web services.

Comment: Like I said above, I think I'd do the same.  However, ARR can be set up to work as a reverse proxy into your network.  It also does a whole host of other stuff as well.